# Are MacBook Pro's two GPUs used simultaneously?

Tags: macbook-pro, gpu

Apple's [top end MacBook Pro](http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/specs-compare.html) comes with both Intel and Radeon. Are both used simultaneously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

- The weak one is used to preserve battery.
- The stronger one is used for performance.

Use [gfxCardStatus](http://codykrieger.com/gfxCardStatus) to control this behavior, or let OS X do it itself:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the situation: The Intel is used for Desktop purposes for energy purposes while the Radeon is used for Graphics and Games for performance purposes. They aren't used simultaneous like [SLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Link_Interface)...

> When you need more performance for things like playing 3D games, editing HD video, or even running CAD software, the 15- and 17-inch MacBook Pro models automatically switch to discrete AMD Radeon graphics that let you see more frames per second and experience better responsiveness.
>
> — [Apple - MacBook Pro - Performance - Up to 3x quicker on the draw. And the render.](http://www.apple.com/macbookpro/performance.html)

Dependent on your OS, you can switch the behavior.